# Java concurrent console IO

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, console

I wrote multithreaded java server-client sockets app with messaging functionality but I encountered a problem with simultaneous console IO.
Main server console is listening for keyboard input and simultaneously printing out messages from the clients. On client side there is a separate thread for printout.
Here is simplified code representation:

```java
public class ServerThread{
....
BufferedReader in = ... (sock.getInputStream);
while(true){
  System.out.println(in.readline());
....
```

```java
public class ServerMain{
.....
BufferedReader keyb = ... (System.in);
while(true){
  in = keyb.readLine();
....
```

The problem occurs while I'm typing something in the main server console and at the same time a message arrives from one of the clients.
That message is then concated to what I was typing on screen and cursor moves to the beginning of the next line waiting for input.
What was typed in previously is stuck in the keyboard buffer, and I cant edit it anymore. Same problem happens on client side.

The question is ***how can I print messages on screen without disrupting ongoing input?***
(inputted text also needs to stay printed on screen as in readLine() default behavior)

I already tried some of the solutions suggested for other similar problems:
***In [Lanterna](https://github.com/mabe02/lanterna) and [JCurses](https://sourceforge.net/projects/javacurses/) libraries there's no support for native System.IO streams.*** I would have to reinvent the wheel and implement it all by myself manually from memory to screen, one char at a time plus build whole console GUI layer. 
The other thing was using [***ANSI codes***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) but I couldn't figure out how to do what I need with them. I could read one input char at a time instead of a whole line, then if message arrives clear the line, move cursor to the beginning and printout, but afterwards in nextline I don't know ***how to print previously buffered text and still be able to delete chars with backspace***.

edit:
**GUI is not an option** as I want my code to be able to run on a headless server.
(also assume that there will be only one terminal, console, shell, and app running per side)

Comment: Your problem is with details of your particular console implementation.  It is unlikely that there is anything you can do about it from Java, and I'm doubtful about doing anything via pre-startup native console configuration, either.  By far your best bet is to avoid having separate threads interacting with the console at the same time.

Comment: No, this is general java console problem, my implementation has nothing to do with it as everything I use is native as you said. I don't expect native java solution, surely there are some libraries or something else that can do this.

Comment: When I say "your particular console implementation" I mean the native one provided by the host system, not Java at all.  The point is that no, you probably *cannot* change the behavior if that's where both threads continue to do their I/O, though you might find the behavior different on a different OS or OS version.  And of course there are libraries that can help: anything that provides an alternative source or destination for one or both of your threads will do.  Even redirecting the output to a file should solve the problem.

Comment: I don't see how a file could help? Instead of a file I made custom buffer in memory but I still have the same problem because everything in memory needs to be reflected on screen. Read the last paragraph of my queston.

Comment: You don't have to reinvent the wheel. You can use a library like JCurses to provide rich console UIs.

Comment: Yes, am aware of JCurses. I haven't tried it out because of poor documentation. But lanterna is more modern version of it and yet there's no builtin support to simply hook native System.IO streams. I would have to do it all by myself manually from memory to screen, one char at a time (aside from building whole console gui layer). Also I'm using Java instead of something low like C for this project mainly because Java is crossplatform but in JCurses there are different libraries for Windows and Unix. I'm gonna reflect this in original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the ideal solution myself:

***[JLine](https://github.com/jline/jline3)*** library works in conjunction with default System.IO, also there is no need to create new Terminal objects (you can) or anything else. Simply instead of `BufferedReader` you use [*LineReader*](https://github.com/jline/jline3/wiki/Using%20line%20readers)

```
String readLine(String prompt, Character mask, String buffer)
```

- *`prompt`* (can be null) is the unexpanded prompt pattern that will be displayed to the user on the left of the input line
- *`mask`* (can also be null) is the character used to hide user input (when reading a password for example)
- ***`buffer` is the initial content of the input line***

**Edit**: *In [JLine's docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.jline/jline/3.11.0/org/jline/reader/LineReader.html#printAbove-java.lang.String-) i found an even better solution:*

> ***printAbove***
>
> *void printAbove(AttributedString str)*
>
> Prints a string before the prompt and redraw everything. If the LineReader is not actually reading a line, the string will simply be
>   printed to the terminal.
>
> Parameters:
>          str - the string to print*

Answer (score 0):

A distinct non-answer, based on: there is only one console.

And that console is an artefact from times when multiple threads weren't a real problem. "Works nicely with multiple threads" was never a requirement for that low level console.

Thus: if you really want a sophisticated solution (that isn't a hack of some sort) simply consider: not using the stdin/stdout console(s).

Instead: write a simple Swing GUI application. Have one text entry field where input is collected, and one or maybe multiple text fields where your output goes. If you want to be fancy, make it a webapp. I am sure that using some framework, you could put together a working thing within a few hours. You will learn more valuable skills by doing that, instead of spending these hours "working around" the fact that you picked the wrong technology for your problem.

Update, given the comment by the OP: then the best I can think of: don't write to the console. Write to different files. Open multiple terminals, and use tools like "tail" to show you what is happening with your output file(s).

Comment: GUI is not an option as I want my code to be able to run on a headless server. But thanks anyway, I forgot to mention this in the description.

Comment: @atanas Then see that last paragraph I just added to my answer.

Comment: Thats an really interesting idea, i will probably use for something else, but this project needs to be one terminal one console one shell one app thing.

Comment: a lot of unix console programs are multithreaded and very sophisticated, console is not an ancient history